# How to personalise email on infobip

Tags: api, email, templates, customization, infobip

Please how can I add custom placeholder to the portal editor for infobip email service.

I have created a template with the portal design editor and I want to dynamically add placeholders like the recipients **first name** or the recipients and **invoice ID** or any other necessary data concerning the recipient, I'm trying to create an invoice email for my customers.

---

From the [API](https://www.infobip.com/docs/api#channels/email/send-email) documentation, I have seen the place to pass in the template ID but I'm not seeing any place where I can pass in my own custom variables for the custom recipient data. so please help if there is any and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to define placeholders in the template you save. Like this: {{customer_name}} {{invoice_no}} and then when you use the template Id in API request you would have to send via API something like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.infobip.com/email/2/send' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Authorization==' \
--form 'templateID="Your_template_id"' \
--form 'to="{
  \"to\": \"Customer1@customer1.com\",
  \"placeholders\": {
    \"customer_name\": \"Customer 1\",
    \"invoice_no\": \"1\"
  }
}

"' \
--form 'to="{  
  \"to\": \"customer2@gmail.com\",
  \"placeholders\": {
    \"customer_name\": \"*customer 2\",
    \"invoice_no\": \"2\"
  }
}"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using as [EmailJs](https://www.emailjs.com/) before. Their integration is extremely simple and straight forward.